# Unable to Access Single Promoted Field Value

Tags: 2013, development, infopath

After creating a form in `InfoPath` and publishing it to `SharePoint`, I can use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` to retrieve all the items from my document library using the following `Key` strings:

```
const string FirstName = "FirstName";
const string MiddleInitial = "_3f304008_6d27_46e4_82e1_81d2ea5d5d84";
const string LastName = "__x007b_39b5c34f_247a_466c_8a76_480f54461087_x007d_";
const string Role = "__x007b_c0bc5325_2cdb_4b7d_8687_eba9cf958f01_x007d_";
const string Department = "Department";
const string JobTitle = "JobTitle"; // __x007b_c0bc5325_2cdb_4b7d_8687_eba9cf958f01_x007d_
const string Office = "";
const string ReportingTo = "_398dc3c8_ff1d_4013_a6e0_139809b37b0d";
const string SecretaryTo = "_cefdf77c_5767_4539_aa5b_098aa3ff0b60";
const string StartDate = "StartDate";
const string FullTime = "_96d926ba_0a82_4773_964a_43d884e5d6d4";
```

Then, while iterating around each `SPListItemCollection` from the Document library:

```
var firstName = item.FieldValues[FirstName];
var middleName = item.FieldValues[MiddleInitial];
var lastName = item.FieldValues[LastName];
var role = item.FieldValues[Role];
var department = item.FieldValues[Department];
var jobTitle = item.FieldValues[JobTitle];          
var office = item.FieldValues[Office];              
var reportingTo = item.FieldValues[ReportingTo];
var secretaryTo = item.FieldValues[SecretaryTo];
var startDate = item.FieldValues[StartDate];
var fullTime = item.FieldValues[FullTime];

var metaData = item.FieldValues["MetaInfo"];
```

This method works fine for all of the fields except for `Office`, which for some reason is not available under `FieldValues` except for inside `MetaInfo`

As you can see, not all of the field names have been sent to `SharePoint` with their proper names (e.g. `"FirstName"` and `"_3f304008_6d27_46e4_82e1_81d2ea5d5d84"`).

I promoted these fields to `SharePoint` by:

1. File -> Publish -> Publish Form to SharePoint Library
2. When asked which fields I want to promote, I selected those mentioned above.
3. Under "Site Column Group", I select `(None: Create new column in this library)`
4. After activating the form, I can access the fields via `SharePoint Designer` and `C#`

---

I have 2 questions:

1. **Why do some of my fields have friendly names, while others seem more like long ID strings?**
2. **What reason would there be for the `Office` field to not promoting properly? I can't see it in my `FieldValues` except for the `MetaInfo` field, which contains all `InfoPath` fields. Note that `Office` is a simple drop-down box in `InfoPath`, similar to `Role` which works perfectly.**

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused because when I originally promoted the field, there already existed a `Managed Metadata` field in that group with the same name - `Office`.

After renaming the group and promoting it again, I am able to access it in the code with

```
_38bb16d7_d38b_4409_aa54_25bd0cb921af
```

And now, when I look in the `FieldValues` I can see that there is an empty `Office` field.

I still don't understand what is going on here but at least I managed to fix the problem.